# How to determine the site protocol using url

Tags: c++, https, port, protocols, winsock

How do I determine (`using c++` and `winsock`) the site protocol based on the URL, for example (`www.google.com`) if the protocol is not known in advance?

Or how do I determine web server TCP port?

I want do an HTTP get request using the link which after `www.` and need to determine the port or protocol, in order to use `http over tls` or `simple http`.

Comment: `www.google.com` is a domain name. protocol is supposed be leading part of url before `:`, for example in url `http://www.google.com` protocol will be `http`

Comment: I need to programmatically recognize the protocol by domain

Comment: It is not possible to figure out protocol just by domain name alone because domain names are not bound to protocols. That is there could be dozens of protocols working with  `www.google.com` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. *You* decide the protocol you're going to use to contact some server. If you haven't decided it, you don't know it. Certainly your computer can't tell you what it will be.

It's like asking a supermarket cashier what you're going to buy today. They don't know that. *You* are supposed to tell *them* that.

What you *can* do is to see whether a website on that server automatically redirects HTTP traffic to a HTTPS URI (thus enforcing SSL), or otherwise blocks non-HTTPS traffic. If that's what you want to do, you can achieve it by attempting to make an HTTP connection to that domain and see what happens.

Depending on your web browser make/model/version, that may be what it is doing when you enter "www.google.com" without specifying a protocol: assuming `http://` then following any remote redirects that take you to `https://` instead. Pretty soon, though, or already if you have certain extensions installed, the default is going to be `https://`. I must stress though, again, that this is still the client (i.e. the browser) making the decision, not the server; if you are writing your own browser then, again, *you* must choose what that default should be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I try connect to web server using port 80, but it works on 443, what server response to me?

Comment: @ВетальВеталь If you try to connect to the web server using port 80, port 443 is completely irrelevant. All that matters is whether the server is listening on port 80 (if not, your connection will fail) and, if so, what it responds with if it does. I recommend you study the HTTP specification to see what possible valid responses exist; the ones that are intended to trigger redirection may be of particular interest to you, but really you ought to study all of it if you're implementing a web client (of course, you didn't tell us what you're doing, so we can only guess).

Comment: I write parser, html pages. Https server uses 443 port, if web server listening 443 port I may guess that server use https protocol. I am right?

Comment: @ВетальВеталь Generally yes though you'll find out when you connect and must still handle the case that an HTTPS service is not what's found there!

Comment: @ВетальВеталь Not really, server listening on 443 port may support multiple protocols at the same time or none at all.

Comment: @VTT How then will you offer?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `www.google.com` is a domain name.
To get protocol you need full urls like 
`https://www.google.com` or `http://www.google.com`
In the above example, `http` and `https` are protocol types.

You can also use `nmap` to determine the open ports, service name and protocol used

Comment: how can I programmatically having a domain name get a url

Comment: You can use `NMAP` tool in your program and parse its output to determine the open ports, service name and protocol used

Comment: No, you need to install `nmap` on your system then you can create the process for the command `NMAP 10.11.15.10` it will provide all protocol used for running service

Comment: I may parse online services with nmap, received string will be has ulr

Comment: Libcurl defines the same?